# How to guarantee each option in a collection is selected only once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using [nested forms](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form), more specifically the `link_to_add` helper, which dynamically generates a new nested form for a new instance with the same fields whenever it is clicked. One of these fields is a `select_tag` with options from a collection. Is there a way to guarantee an item from the collection can be selected once for all instances that are being created in the same form?

**To put it more simply**: Is there a way to disable or remove options from a collection dynamically once they have been selected on a `select_tag`, so that other `select_tag`s that use the same collection won't allow that option to be selected again?

Comment: you need to use javascript to update available options whenever a value changes

Comment: @ThomasSevestre yeah, I ended up implementing it with javascript. Was hoping I could avoid it